# Allow user to see all of their posts using mongoose / nextjs / react

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, api, next.js, state

I am trying to create a my-posts page which will consist of all the posts made by the user.

User Schema

```
const userSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
email: { type: String},
password: { type: String},
name: { type: String},
createdAt: { type: String},
posts: [{ type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'}]
},{
timestamps: true,
});
```

Posts Schema

```
const postSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
name: { type: String},
category: { type: String},
userId: {type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"},
},{
    timestamps: true
});
```

Creating a new post

```
handler.post(async(req, res) => {
await db.connect();
const newPost = new Post({
    name: req.body.name,
    category: req.body.category,
    userId: req.body.userId
})



const userBy = await User.findById(userId)

const thePost = await newPost.save();
userBy.posts = user.posts.concat(post._id)
await user.save()

await db.disconnect();


});


export default handler;
```

Retrieve 'My Posts'

```
export async function getServerSideProps( {query} ) {


await db.connect();
const data = await User.findById(req.query.id).populate("vehicles").lean

await database.disconnect();



const userPosts = data.map(database.convertObj)




return {
  props: {
    userPosts
  }
 }
}
```

I'm not too sure how to pass the current logged in users _id to the getServerSideProps to then query the database for all the posts attached to that user in the posts array. If there is a better way to approach this please let me know or if you know what I am currently doing wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an area where you might want to use a request from the client side to get the data, as suggested by the [Nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#fetching-data-on-the-client-side) rather than using `getServerSideProps`.

But if you *really* want to do it with SSR, you can use `getServerSideProps` and pass in data (like the userId) to `getServerSideProps` through the [context parameter](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter) as either a `query` or a `parameter`.

If you want to do it as a query, you can get `query` as a prop, as you are already doing, or you can do it using a `param` like in [this codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-data-from-an-api-on-the-server-side-with-getserversideprops-in-nextjs-vrh8w?from-embed&initialpath=%2Fuser%2F3)